# Why my Qt signal is not processed by the event queue?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qt5.8

### Quick description of the situation

I am trying to have a minimal GUI starting an endless process that communicates over a custom protocol over a CAN bus.

Based on what I have read [here](https://wiki.qt.io/Threads_Events_QObjects), I structured my code as follows:

I have on one hand a class handling my GUI with 2 simple push buttons "start" and "stop", namely MainWindow.

And on the other hand, a class that manages my custom protocol with a state machine as described in the link above, namely Worker.

In the middle of these, I have a controller that links the whole together. This controller is here because some other tasks are handled but this is not the purpose of this post.

### Regarding signals and slot

I have connected my buttons signals (released()) to signals from the Controller. So the GUI does not know what exactly is starting.

Those Controller's signals are connected to slots from the Worker. These slots are there to start and stop the process.

### Regarding threads

The Worker instance lives in its own QThread. Other tasks may be involved so I figured out it would be better to handle each one in its own thread.

One started, the process of the worker is handled through signals/slots that make the state machine evolved across the states regarding the transitions. Because of the signal/slot mechanism, the thread's event loop can process events from its queue, if I'm correct.

### The problem

My starting signal is correctly sent to the worker, starting the process and therefore the state machine. This machine is cyclic until the stop signal is requested by the user. But, when the user clicks on the button "stop", the slot associated is not called. Meanwhile, the machine continues to run endlessly and does not see the stop request (I have put some debug messages to see what was really executed).

### Code snippets

Here are code snippets.
MainWindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

#include "controller.h"

class QPushButton;
class QWidget;
class QVBoxLayout;

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(Controller& controller, QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Controller& controller;

    QPushButton* startButton;
    QPushButton* stopButton;
    QWidget* centralWidget;
    QVBoxLayout* layout;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

MainWindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

#include <QWidget>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QPushButton>

MainWindow::MainWindow(Controller &controller, QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent), controller(controller)
{
    centralWidget = new QWidget(this);
    setCentralWidget(centralWidget);

    layout = new QVBoxLayout();
    startButton = new QPushButton("START", this);
    stopButton = new QPushButton("STOP", this);

    layout->addWidget(startButton);
    layout->addWidget(stopButton);

    centralWidget->setLayout(layout);

    connect(startButton, SIGNAL(released()), &controller, SIGNAL(startSignal()));
    connect(stopButton, SIGNAL(released()), &controller, SIGNAL(stopSignal()));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete stopButton;
    delete startButton;
    delete layout;
    delete centralWidget;
}
```

Controller.h

```
#ifndef CONTROLLER_H
#define CONTROLLER_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QThread>

class MainWindow;
class Worker;

class Controller : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Controller();
    virtual ~Controller();

signals:
    void startSignal() const;
    void stopSignal() const;

private:
    MainWindow* mainWindow;

    QThread workerThread;
    Worker* worker;
};

#endif // CONTROLLER_H
```

Controller.cpp (inherits public QObject)

```
#include "controller.h"

#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "worker.h"

Controller::Controller()
{
    mainWindow = new MainWindow(*this);
    mainWindow->show();

    worker = new Worker();
    worker->moveToThread(&workerThread);
    connect(this, SIGNAL(startSignal()), worker, SLOT(startProcess()));
    connect(this, SIGNAL(stopSignal()), worker, SLOT(stopProcess()));
    workerThread.start();
}

Controller::~Controller()
{
    workerThread.quit();
    workerThread.wait();

    delete worker;
    delete mainWindow;
}
```

Worker handles a state machine with `State` and `Transition` which are enumerations.
Worker.h

```
#ifndef WORKER_H
#define WORKER_H

#include <QObject>

class Worker : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    enum State { IDLE, STATE_1, STATE_2 };
    enum Transition { OK, ERROR };
    enum Mode { MODE_1, MODE_2 };
    explicit Worker();

    void read();

public slots:
    void startProcess();
    void stopProcess();

    void processEvent(const Transition& transition);

signals:
    void sendSignal(const Transition& transition) const;

private:
    State currentState;
    Mode selectedMode;
    bool stopRequested;
};

#endif // WORKER_H
```

Worker.cpp (inherits public QObject)

```
#include "worker.h"

#include <QDebug>
#include <QThread>

Worker::Worker() : QObject()
{
    stopRequested = false;
    currentState = IDLE;

    connect(this, SIGNAL(sendSignal(Transition)), this, SLOT(processEvent(Transition)));
}

void Worker::read()
{
    qDebug() << "Reading...";
    QThread::msleep(500);
    emit sendSignal(OK);
}

void Worker::startProcess()
{
    qDebug() << "Start requested";
    selectedMode = MODE_1;
    stopRequested = false;
    emit sendSignal(OK);
}

void Worker::stopProcess()
{
    qDebug() << "Stop requested";
    stopRequested = true;
}

void Worker::processEvent(const Worker::Transition &transition)
{
    qDebug() << "Process event";
    switch(currentState) {
    case IDLE:
        switch(selectedMode) {
        case MODE_1:
            currentState = STATE_1;
            read();
            break;
        case MODE_2:
            currentState = STATE_2;
            break;
        }
        break;
    case STATE_1:
        if (!stopRequested) {
            if (transition == OK) {
                read();
            } else {
                currentState = IDLE;
                // No emission. The state machine stops on error
            }
        }
        break;
    case STATE_2:
        // Not implemented yet
        break;
    }
}
```

.pro file

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = sample_project
TEMPLATE = app

DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp \
    controller.cpp \
    worker.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h \
    controller.h \
    worker.h
```

**DISCLAIMER** The code does not quit properly. Better launch it in your IDE so your can kill it easily.

These code snippets have been built with Qt5.8.0 MinGW 32bits.
To reproduce the problem, just hit "start", debug messages appear in the console. Then hit "stop" and the messages keep coming and do not stop as they should.

I have found a workaround by calling directly `stopProcess()` from the `Controller` instead of using a signal. Doing so sets correctly `stopRequested` and stops the process.

Though, I was wondering why the event queue is never processing the signal from the `Controller` ? Even with the state machine handled with signal/slots, allowing the event queue to process events as they arrive.

(I have tried putting a intermediary slot in the `Controller` that sends the signal to the `Worker` to see if the GUI correctly sent the signal and this slot is indeed executed. But the `stopProcess()` slot remains uncalled.)

Any thoughts ?

Comment: Can you reproduce this with a [mcve]?  That would make it easier for others to reproduce and solve your problem.

Comment: It sounds as if your `Worker` thread is busy rather than returning to the `Qt` event processing loop.  What exactly does `someWork()` do in `Worker::processEvent`?

Comment: You seem to believe that `sendSignal` is sent to `processEvent` via a queued connection. It is actually sent via direct connection as signal and slot are both in the same worker. Maybe you want a `Qt::QueuedConnection`?

Comment: @G.M. Since no hardware is yet connected to my application, someWork() runs a `QThread.msleep(1000);`. In the end, it will handle a communication read protected with a timeout, hence the check for error juste below.

Comment: In your `Controller` constructor you try to connect to a signal named `stopignal` -- typo in your post or actual code?

Comment: @G.M. Typo. I corrected it. This is not actual code. I'm building a MCVE to edit my post ;)

Comment: @Oktalist You mean that all "inner signals" are direct connected so executed on top of the queue regardless what's in it ? This would explain why the "stop signal" is never processed since it's sent from another thread so added to the queue and there would be always one signal to process before it is its turn to be processed.

Comment: @TobySpeight Good point. I edited the post to change the code snippets by actual MCVE. Feel free to try it.

Comment: @PlikPlok I guess what @Oktalist means is whenever you call `emit sendSignal(...)` within your Worker class it is essentially just like a function call since it's a direct connection in the same thread.

Comment: Right. It's not "on top of the queue", it's not in the queue at all. Calling `sendSignal` just results in a direct and immediate function call to `processEvent`. Just step through `processEvent` in the debugger to see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by Oktalist, the problem is that you are never returning to the Qt's event loop in your worker thread. By default Qt uses a [`Qt::AutoConnection`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum), which is a `Qt::DirectConnection` if the receiver lives in the same thread. So, Qt calls `processEvent` recursively in an infinite way.

**Solution 1:** write/read `stopRequested` from both threads.

As you suggested, calling `stopProcess` from the `Controller` directly may solve your problem, but is not thread safe. You can define `stopRequested` as `volatile`, but this will only [work on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6995486/7621674) and will [probably work in other situations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6592379/7621674).

A better approach is to [define it as `std::atomic`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16111663/do-i-have-to-use-atomicbool-for-exit-bool-variable) if C++11 is an option for you.

**Solution 2:** avoid recursive function call

You can specify as fifth argument of [`QObject::connect`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#connect) which type of connection you want. Choosing a `Qt::QueuedConnection` will break your recursive action. In this way, Qt will be able to handle your `stopRequested` signal.

The advantage of this method is that all the thread safety concerns are handled transparently by Qt, but this will make your state machine somewhat slower.

Comment: Thank you all. I indeed tried to connect with `Qt::QueuedConnection` and the stop signal is correctly handled. I think i will go for it because I suppose that the speed decrease is limited and harmless regarding my communication timings. I shall run some tests to verify that as soon as I got something to communicate to :p.